# How to check if two fields match in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Im new to javascript and i have this kind of problem. I have two fields and they must be checked if the input inside is the same. If they are the same an alert should popup to tell so. Thanks in advance.

Here is an example of my fields:

[image: Here is an example of my fields]

```js
function writeText() {
  n = "has been collected " + window.document.myform.exemplu1.value;
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = n;
}

function writePass() {
  n = window.document.myform.exemplu2.value;
  alert("password is " + n);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3> Example</h3>
  <form name="myform">
    <p> <input name="exemplu1" type="text" value="Edit field" onBlur="writeText()" size="25" maxlength="30" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span id="content">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p> <input name="exemplu2" type="password" value="Parola" onBlur="writePass()" size="15" maxlength="15" /></p>

  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality).

I have bound a callback using `adEventListener` to the `click` event of a button to perform the check.

```js
const buttonEl = document.querySelector('button')
const usernameEl = document.getElementById('username')
const passwordEl = document.getElementById('password')

buttonEl.addEventListener('click', () => usernameEl.value === passwordEl.value ? console.log('They are the same') : console.log('They are different'))
```

```css
 * {
   color: #DDD;
   background-color: white;
   font-size: 1.1em;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username" />
<input type="password" id="password" />
<button>Check</button>
```